# В чем ошибка скрипта?

Tags: javascript, jquery

### **Доброго времени суток.**

Пишу небольшую игру на стеке html, css, js (JQuery). 
Пытаюсь запилить передвижение по карте. 
Помогите скорректировать код для движение вверх и вниз героя.

```
$( document ).keypress(function(event) {
    var positionCamera = $(".game-camera__map").css("transform");
    // Объединить через регулярку
    positionCamera = positionCamera.substr(19, );
    positionCamera = positionCamera.replace(")", "");

    // Позиция камеры относительно карты по X
    var positionCameraX = positionCamera.replace(/[, ]\d*/ig, ""),
        positionCameraX = Number(positionCameraX),            
        // Позиция камеры относительно карты по Y
        positionCameraY = positionCamera.replace(/\d*[, ]/ig, ""),
        positionCameraY = Number(positionCameraY);

    if (event.charCode == 100) { // Right
      positionCameraX = Number(positionCameraX - speedHero);
      camera.css("transform", "translate("+ positionCameraX +"px, "+ positionCameraY +"px)");
    } else if (event.charCode == 97) { // Left
      positionCameraX = positionCameraX + speedHero;
      camera.css("transform", "translate("+ positionCameraX +"px, "+ positionCameraY +"px)");
    } else if (event.charCode == 115) { // Down
      positionCameraY = positionCameraY - speedHero;
      camera.css("transform", "translate("+ positionCameraX +"px, "+ positionCameraY +"px)");
    } else if (event.charCode == 119) { // Up
      positionCameraY = positionCameraY + speedHero;
      camera.css("transform", "translate("+ positionCameraX +"px, "+ positionCameraY +"px)");
    }
});
```

*Ошибка где то в этих строчках.* 
**Полный пример, тут:**
https://codepen.io/AndreyMyP/pen/GdMEyP?editors=1010

Comment: Почему ты думаешь, что тут есть ошибка?

Comment: @Grundy Передвижение вверх и вниз некорректно себя ведет,
 попробуй на глянуть codepen:
event.charCode == 115 (клавиша s) и
event.charCode == 119 (клавиша w)

Comment: @Grundy Предполагаю что ошибка в моменте, когда я пытаюсь брать значение transform: translate с класса камеры, а именно в этой строчке
var positionCamera = $(".game-camera__map").css("transform");
мне возвращает матрицу значений и я пытаюсь спарсить нужное transitionX или Y, посредством регулярного выражения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### transform: translate

Ошибка была в неправильном парсинге значения transform: translate. 
При попытке узнать значение js, 
выдавалось матричное значение, а именно:

**Ввод:** 
$(".game-camera__map").css("transform"); 
**Вывод:** 
"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)" 
*typeof is str* 

**Правильное решение:** 
Необходимо было матричную строку преобразовать в массив по символу "," после чего обратиться по элементу массива.

```
var positionCamera = $(".game-camera__map").css("transform");
var positionCamera = positionCamera.split('(')[1],
    positionCamera = positionCamera.split(')')[0],
    positionCamera = positionCamera.split(',');

// Позиция камеры относительно карты по X
var positionCameraX = positionCamera[4],
    positionCameraX = Number(positionCameraX);  

// Позиция камеры относительно карты по Y
var positionCameraY = positionCamera[5],
    positionCameraY = Number(positionCameraY);
```

**Решение взял из статьи:** 
https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/

**Решение на codepen!** 
https://codepen.io/AndreyMyP/pen/GdMEyP